# How to apply multi ngif to data display on table?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular7, angular-components

How to apply multi *ngIf to data returned to table?

I need to control column name based on multi condition *ngIf but i don't know which tag used and where :

```
*ngIf="coln=repcon.fieldName && repcon.columnType=1" then display data as icon link on field onlineurl
*ngIf="coln=repcon.fieldName && repcon.columnType=2" then make it as hidden field to field onlineurl
```

I work on angular 7 app I displayed dynamic data no fixed header or content

```
 <thead >
                  <tr>
                    <th  *ngFor="let coln of headerCols">


                        {{coln}}

                    </th>


                  </tr>
                </thead>
 <tbody>
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let repcon of ReportControl">
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let repdata of ReportData">
                    <tr *ngFor="let rep of reportdetailslist">

                      <td *ngFor="let coln of headerCols">

                        <span>{{rep[coln]}}</span>
                   // i think here can applied multi ng if but which tag used .
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                  </ng-container>
                </ng-container>

                </tbody>
sample data

ReportId   onlineurl          reportdate
1222       localhost:5000/    12-12-2018
1222       localhost:7000/    12-01-2019
1222       localhost:9000/    12-12-2020
control report
reportid  fieldname   columntype
1222       onlineurl     1
```

Comment: You can have multiple `div` tags there having *ngIf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your conditions, you can nest *ngIf :

```
<td *ngFor="let coln of headerCols">
    <div *ngIf="coln=repcon.fieldName">

        <div *ngIf="repcon.columnType=1">data as icon link</div>

        <div *ngIf="repcon.columnType=2">hidden field</div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Or with *ngSwitch :

```
<td *ngFor="let coln of headerCols">
    <div *ngIf="coln=repcon.fieldName" [ngSwitch]="repcon.fieldName">

        <div *ngSwitchCase="1">data as icon link</div>

        <div *ngSwitchCase="2">hidden field</div>

    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: OK thank you for reply how to display data as icon link

Comment: I don't know, your question was "How to apply multi ngif?", so I answered it. What does  "display data as icon link" mean? What's an "icon link" ?

Comment: icon link meaning display text URL as a link with shot name url link

Comment: What, you mean a simple link like `<a href="https://full.url.here">Click here</a>` ?